# EC2 API ImportKeyPair: DER and OpenSSH public key canot be imported

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to import public keys by EC2 API function: ImportKeyPair.
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-ImportKeyPair.html

I created request URL:
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=&Action=ImportKeyPair&Expires=2012-03-07T23%3A28%3A01.000001Z&KeyName=super-key&PublicKeyMaterial=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCz2SBCBAynBnZ8mTxPVGSYufy4NjuvKTpR%0D%0AI4rqA%2FnQPCN2oz3qZsq2N%2Burk3YduutFaXcPgZGPPFib%2BzzRBs8XQUuNl1NvalINQrK3nnox%0D%0AhSjhuY1o8J9aA7qb6uykOweQ7uURSAZcgjNwm53u1EZ2PSD5AKRsKE1b2V2gnp1HGwIDAQAB&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&SignatureVersion=2&Version=2011-12-15&Signature=WPKdf0D4VLxSUlM7UUqUddDJudA%3D

But this action returns:
\n`InvalidKeyPair.Format`Invalid DER encoded key material730439ac-31ef-4757-bfa4-0341517b39e7
I tried different variants of keys:
'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCz2SBCBAynBnZ8mTxPVGSYufy4NjuvKTpRI4rqA/nQPCN2oz3qZsq2N+urk3YduutFaXcPgZGPPFib+zzRBs8XQUuNl1NvalINQrK3nnoxhSjhuY1o8J9aA7qb6uykOweQ7uURSAZcgjNwm53u1EZ2PSD5AKRsKE1b2V2gnp1HGw=='

and 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCz2SBCBAynBnZ8mTxPVGSYufy4NjuvKTpRI4rqA/nQPCN2oz3qZsq2N+urk3YduutFaXcPgZGPPFib+zzRBs8XQUuNl1NvalINQrK3nnoxhSjhuY1o8J9aA7qb6uykOweQ7uURSAZcgjNwm53u1EZ2PSD5AKRsKE1b2V2gnp1HGw=='

and 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQCz2SBCBAynBnZ8mTxPVGSYufy4NjuvKTpRI4rqA/nQPCN2oz3qZsq2N+urk3YduutFaXcPgZGPPFib+zzRBs8XQUuNl1NvalINQrK3nnoxhSjhuY1o8J9aA7qb6uykOweQ7uURSAZcgjNwm53u1EZ2PSD5AKRsKE1b2V2gnp1HGw== aaaa@mac-aaaa.gmz'
All such keys returns an error in ImportKeyPair :-(

What is wrong????

Answer (score 0):

This stumped me for a while too.

You need to base64 encode whatever you send as key material, even if it is already base64 encoded.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/boto-dev/IczrStO9Q8M